# How to produce X mark in html.

Tags: html

With the following code:

```
<span style="color:#008A00;font-size:11pt"> &#x2713; Tick </span>
```

I could able to get tick mark. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hhxa7uzf/). I tried this for ✗ mark:

```
<span style="color:#008A00;font-size:11pt"> &#x274c;  Wrong </span>
```

but it doesn't work. I got the hex code of ✗ from [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/274c/index.htm).

Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: That is because the symbol is not present in the font that you are using.

Comment: `&#x2718;` and `&#x2718;`  work for me.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Html entity `&cross;` ✗ as well.

Take a look [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) (Search for 'cross')

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/quwm4ptv/)

```html
<span style="color:#008A00;font-size:11pt"> &cross;  Wrong </span>
```

Comment: Using an entity instead of a numeric character reference does not improve the odds of having the character displayed; quite the contrary. In addition, `&cross;`, when supported at all, denotes U+2714, which is not the character that the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

As the [fileformat.info page cited](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/274c/index.htm) says, the character denoted by `&#x274c;`, i.e. CROSS MARK (U+274C) “❌”, was added to Unicode in version 6 in 2010. This means that most fonts don’t contain it. The [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/274c/fontsupport.htm) page lists only a few fonts. Most computers in the world do not have any of these fonts installed; moreover, even if a suitable font exists, browsers may fail to use it unless you explicitly list it in a `font-family` declaration. So you would need to use `@font-face` to have it rendered in a cross-browser way.

If you actually meant to use U+2717 BALLOT X “✗”, then you can use `&#x2717;` (or enter the character as such). But CROSS MARK is what refer to as the character you tried to use; note that a comment in the Unicode standard says about it: “forms a game tally pair with 2B55”. So if you want to use CROSS MARK “❌”, it would be consistent to pair it with U+2B55 HEAVY LARGE CIRCLE “⭕”.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<span style="color:#008A00;font-size:11pt"> &#x2718; Test </span>
```

`&#x2718;` You need this code.

http://jsfiddle.net/msq7zppn/

Comment: This is a different character, so this does not answer the question asked.

Comment: Okay what is the difference please explain.

Comment: 2718 is not 274C (or 2717).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. My guess is that the font you are using doesn't contain this particular unicode symbol. Do you get a rectangle instead?

What you should try is using a different font family, or an embedded web font.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<span style="color:#008A00;font-size:11pt"> &#x2717; Wrong </span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bandon/hhxa7uzf/1/

`&#x2717;` means code of ✗.

Comment: This is a different character, so this does not answer the question asked.